# SlideMenuControllerSwift implementation in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift-extensions, objective-c-swift-bridge

I try to add [SlideMenuControllerSwift](https://github.com/dekatotoro/SlideMenuControllerSwift) in Objective-c.

I can access **[slideMenuController openLeft]** in my AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    ViewController *main = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
    LeftViewController *left = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LeftViewController"];

    UINavigationController *nvc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:main];
    left.mainViewController = nvc;

    SlideMenuController *slideMenuController = [[SlideMenuController alloc] init];

    slideMenuController = [slideMenuController initWithMainViewController:nvc leftMenuViewController:left];

    [slideMenuController openLeft]; // appears with open menu

    self.window.rootViewController = slideMenuController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
 }
```

The [SlideMenuControllerSwift](https://github.com/dekatotoro/SlideMenuControllerSwift/blob/master/Source/SlideMenuController.swift) has UIViewController extension.

```
extension UIViewController {
 ....
    public func toggleLeft() {
        slideMenuController()?.toggleLeft()
    }
```

But how to access toggleLeft() in obj-c ViewController.m ?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this link.
https://github.com/romaonthego/RESideMenu

In this example you can get flow of the implementing side menu.